# Read Only fields in Datasheet view 2010 are Editable in 2013

Tags: migration, datasheet, read-only, quick-edit

We migrated a list from 2010 to 2013. The 2010 Version used an Access Web Datasheet View. 2013 uses the Quick Edit / Datasheet view. The fields that were Multiple Lines of text (Enhanced Rich) have the same type in 2013. However, you CAN edit these in 2013 whereas in 2010, you CANNOT; They were Read only in the 2010 Datasheet view.

How do we set fields to be read only in the Datasheet view for 2013. Did we miss some permissions or settings during the migration from 2010?